# What are the NCS journals?

Tags: publications, journals

I have seen people mentioning special group of journal, namely NCS journals, but what does it stand for? When people say that "faculty has to publish in NCS to get a shot at tenure", what does it mean? Googling doesn't return anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NCS stands for "Nature, Cell, Science", the top journals in STEM and biomedical fields. The [impact factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_factor) of these journals are among highest, between 36 and 41.

[Some have noticed](https://twitter.com/JSheltzer/status/1093027545392521217) that publication in NCS journal correlates with academic career success (getting tenure-track position at the top university), while [others commented](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2013/dec/09/how-journals-nature-science-cell-damage-science) that degree of attention to these top journals is bad for science.